# Upgrading BlinkID SDK what are the replacement for the old delegates and types?

Tags: microblink, blinkid

Im upgrading an old app that uses old BlinkID SDK, in the app they're using the following delegates and types

PPScanningDelegate
PPCameraCoordinator
PPRecognizerResult
PPDocumentClassifier
PPOcrLayout
PPMetadata
PPImageMetadata
PPCameraCoordinator
PPScanningViewController

is there a one to one replacement for these in the new BlinkID SDK? the new SDK im upgrading to is 5.16.1

Answer (score 2):

If you're upgrading from an older version (like v3) of BlinkID to v5, maybe this [documentation](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios#3-initiating-the-scanning-process) will be useful.

There you can see how to set up the recognizer for document scanning and reading, the scanning UI and how to handle the scanning results since a lot of things have changed with version 5.

Another thing I would recommend taking a look at is the [BlinkID](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios#-blinkid-recognizer) ([Combined](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios#-blinkid-combined-recognizer)) recognizer which is mainly used with version 5 to read and extract document information.

I also recommend taking a look at the [sample application](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios/blob/master/Samples/BlinkID-sample-Swift/BlinkID-sample-Swift/ViewController.swift) where you can see how the SDK has been implemented into the sample project.